# SUM of all calculated columns looking at each individual criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So what I need: I have code where I have defined Actuals, Forecast and Absolute Error for each title in each location.

Does someone know if I can do this calculation over here in one SQL statement?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `DMDUNIT` from your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT
   b.[LOC]/*, b.[DMDUNIT]*/, SUM(b.HistoryQuantity) AS 'Actuals', SUM(a.TOTFCST) AS 'Forecast'
   ,SUM(ABS(b.HistoryQuantity - a.TOTFCST)) AS 'Abs Error', SUM(ABS(b.HistoryQuantity - a.TOTFCST))/SUM(b.HistoryQuantity) 'Abs Error/Actuals'

FROM

   SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC a

JOIN

   SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN b ON a.[STARTDATE] = b.[DMDPostDate]

                            AND a.[DMDUNIT] = b.[DMDUNIT]

                            AND a.[LOC] = b.[LOC]

GROUP BY

   b.[LOC]/*, b.[DMDUNIT]*/

ORDER BY

   b.[LOC]/*, b.[DMDUNIT]*/
```